# How to find input impedance of RA30H1317M1 RF power amplifier module?

Tags: amplifier, rf, ham-radio, vhf

I am building an amateur radio VHF transmitter. I want to use off the shelf transmitter module like [DRA818V](http://www.dorji.com/docs/data/DRA818V.pdf) (or similar) as the drive amplifier and [RA30H1317M1](https://www.mitsubishielectric-mesh.com/products/pdf/ra30h1317m1.pdf) as the final amplifier.

This is my idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6QsPF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The driver outputs 500mW, while the RA30H1317M1 has absolute maximum input power of 100mW. I have studied datasheet of RA30H1317M1, but I can't find the input impedance. If I knew the input impedance, then I could calculate the divider.

My questions:

1. Is it okay to drive RA30H1317M1 this way, or what is the proper way to do it?
2. Should there also be an LPF between the amplifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test block diagram show input matched into 50 ohms, and electrical spec says input match is better then 3:1, so it seems likely that things input is specified to be somewhere in the 3:1 circle around a nominal 50 ohms restive.

Note that full shout is specified at 50mW input, meaning your driver is good for ~10dB more then you need, personally I would pick a smaller driver stage, it will reduce your power consumption, the final is not linear anyway so IMD is not a concern.

Some pad at the input is not a horrible thing, maybe 3dB or so at a nominal 50 ohms, it helps with stability. 
A BPF at the input is usually pretty nasty unless you know what you are doing, you do not want the filter output to go high Z where the amp still has gain or it will honk.

Comment: Thank you. So I can simply put a 10dB attenuator using 1206 resistors (like here http://blog.novaeletronica.com.br/en/tabela-de-atenuador-de-rf-com-resistores/ ) between the amps?